# Merging MDI menu

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a main form with the following MenuStrip

```
File          Window
 New Child
 Exit
```

And a second MDI child with these items

```
File    Edit
  Save
  New
```

no matter how I set the properties `MergeAction` for both of this `ToolStrip` objects I cannot get such a structure after the child form is displayed for the main menu.

```
File Window Edit
```

where `File` would be merged nicely with the items form child window.

Any other ideas how to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Set parent:` **New Child** *merge index* to **2**
`Set parent:` **Exit** *merge index* to **3**
`Set child:` **File** *merge action* to **MatchOnly**
`Set child:` **Save** *merge action* to **Insert** and *merge index* to **0**
`Set child:` **New** *merge action* to **Insert** and *merge index* to **1**

Leave all other to default settings.
Also both `MenuStrips` must have their property `AllowMerge` set to `true`

Comment: That seems to work, not quite friendly as in my old WinAPI application, but at least I have something to work around. Thx

Comment: The mergeIndex on the parent menu items are irrelevant as far as I can tell.